How can I change the background color of the Firebase notification icon in Flutter?
I'm utilizing FCM for notifications, and I've encountered an inconvenience due to the app icon being black. When notifications are displayed, the first notification icon is encircled by white, while the second one retains its own color. How can I set black background color for the first notification icon, similar to the second notification?

I have used the following way but didn't work
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/black"/>
Any suggestions are appreciated

have you found anything in the meantime? Having the same issue.
